# DataFrame.assign doesn't work in dask? Trying to create new column based on existing column

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I have a really large txt file with more than **200 mil rows**. The file is too big for main memory, so I need to use **dask** to perform some tasks on it.

Each row contains street name and number. My job is to put street name in one column (no matter how many names the row has) and the number in other column. Each column is separated by new line character.

The example of txt file:

```
Street Name 13682
Street 2
Street Name Street 34
Street street s 56
S Name 78627
Name Street 45672929081
```

The number is always at the end of the name, but the length of the number varies.
So, my goal is to have dask df with two columns, first one with street name, and the next one with number as int.

What I've tried:

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import numpy as np 

streets = dd.read_csv('streets.txt', blocksize='25MB',header=None, names=['name']) # 25MB chunks  
streets.compute()

#now I want to create new column with just a number:

streets.assign(id_num=streets['name'].astype('str').str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int))
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 streets.assign(id_num=streets['name'].astype('str').str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int))

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py:4686, in DataFrame.assign(self, **kwargs)
   4677 for k, v in kwargs.items():
   4678     if not (
   4679         isinstance(v, Scalar)
   4680         or is_series_like(v)
   (...)
   4684         or isinstance(v, Array)
   4685     ):
-> 4686         raise TypeError(
   4687             f"Column assignment doesn't support type {typename(type(v))}"
   4688         )
   4689     if callable(v):
   4690         kwargs[k] = v(data)

TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame
```

I also need to delete numbers from the first column so I have only street names in it.

My preferred output would be:

[wanted dask dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF8z6.png)

Thanks!

Comment: quick q - does `streets["id_num"] = ...` or `streets[["id_num"]] = ...` work? wondering if this is just an assign issue or if something else is going on

Comment: Hi, no, I get this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' when I add to brackets

Comment: hmm that sounds like a different problem though. are you able to just assign the result to a variable? it sounds like something is causing `streets['name'].astype('str')` to be a DataFrame rather than a series. any chance you could provide a [mre]?

Comment: and if not, can you confirm whether this is 100% of your code? like if you restart your python session can you run straight through your code and get this error? if you assign that to a variable rather than to a column, and you still get that error, will you update your question to show that exact traceback as well as the result of `print(df.head())` and `print(df)` (for the data types and spec)?

Comment: Could you please write the whole code to assign new variable to my df? 
streets["id_num"] =...? because I read that dask.dataframe.DataFrame.assign is the only way to assign new column. @MichaelDelgado

Comment: I just mean I bet `new_var = streets['name'].astype('str').str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)` would fail too, based on your comments. it would be helpful if you could confirm

Comment: Also, it's weird that when I create new df with the same code, it works (I get column with just numbers), but .assign doesn't work with existing dataframe. `new_df = streets['name'].astype('str').str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
new_df.compute()`

Comment: oh ok - and new_df is a DataFrame? that seems to be the part that dask is tripping up - it makes sense that you can't assign a dataframe as a column but it's weird that this is returning a dataframe. does `streets.assign(id_num=streets['name'].astype('str').str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)["name"])` work? if so, you might have found a bug

Comment: no, it doesn't work.  it returns: KeyError: 'name'.

Nor does this line work:
`streets['id_num']=streets.name.astype('str').str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)` 
It again gives error:
TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame

Comment: huh this is a weird one. sorry! :/